# Symfony 4: How to remove doctrine integrity constraint violation?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

My `Post` entity looks like this:

```
<?php

// ...

class Post
{

 /**
 * The ID generated manually.
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=3)
 */
private $id;

//...

/**
 * One Post has One Post.
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="DovStone\Bundle\BlogAdminBundle\Entity\Post", fetch="EAGER")
 * @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $parent;
```

One insertion works as expected and I can even get the parent `$post->getParent()` of a given post.

A problem occures when I try to make **another post insertion which has the same parent as the previous post inserted successfuly**.

I'll make this following example so you can get clearly what I mean:

Insertion #1:
**Id**: 613
**Parent**: NULL `//success`

Insertion #2:
**Id**: 156
**Parent**: 613 `//success`

Insertion #3:
**Id**: 156
**Parent: 613** `//fail`

Insertion #3 returns me `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 UNIQUE constraint failed` because I think insertion #2 has already its parent it as **613**.

So what should I do to tell doctrine `parent_id` column must not be unique as `id` column.

Comment: Well, you make a `OneToOne` relation when obviously you need `OneToMany`, because one parent can have many post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your relation from

```
@ORM\OneToOne
```

to

```
@ORM\ManyToOne
```

Like this:

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="DovStone\Bundle\BlogAdminBundle\Entity\Post", inversedBy="DovStone\Bundle\BlogAdminBundle\Entity\Post", fetch="EAGER")
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
```

Answer (score 1):

If your $parent class could have more than one child, it should be usually mapped as ManyToOne relation